# Why can I render a square without a shader?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am learning about shaders and it seems like they are a program in the GPU that tells it how to do things, like binding an object with a color. Then I do not get how this code can work and draw a square with colors without using a shader:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


# include <GL/glew.h>
# include <GL/freeglut.h>
# include <GL/glext.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")

// Drawing routine.
void drawScene(void)
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

   // Draw a polygon with specified vertices.
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(80.0, 20.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(80.0, 80.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(20.0, 80.0, 0.0);
   glEnd();

   glFlush();
}

// Initialization routine.
void setup(void)
{
   glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}

// OpenGL window reshape routine.
void resize(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0, -1.0, 1.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
}

// Keyboard input processing routine.
void keyInput(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch(key)
   {
      case 27:
         exit(0);
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}

// Main routine.
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);

#ifdef _WIN32
  glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
  glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE);
#endif

   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
   glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
   glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow("square.cpp");
   glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
   glutReshapeFunc(resize);
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput);

#ifdef _WIN32
   glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
   glewInit();
#endif

   setup();

   glutMainLoop();
}
```

Also, [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) for drawing a triangle *does* use shaders, so why would the code above not need shaders when the goal basically is the same?

Comment: The code above is old OpenGL code (useing the Fixed Function Pipeline), and it alows you to create a a square without shader. But the advantage of modern OpenGL that uses Buffers and Shaders, is that it allows to create code that runs much faster and to use all modern features the GPU provides.

Answer (score 3):

1. You're using the old fixed function pipeline, which predates shaders and is no longer part of modern OpenGL versions (still available for compatibility reasons in most distributions, but you shouldn't use it for new programs).
2. Even if you weren't, the OpenGL API doesn't specify what should happen if you make a mistake. If you don't have shaders bound in new code (which requires them) the implementation is theoretically allowed to use AI to analyze your program and figure out what you meant to do. It'll probably not do that, but sometimes you still might get somewhat reasonable results - for example, if no fragment shader is bound all fragments might be displayed with a white color.

Answer (score 0):

Cubic's answer is perfectly correct, I'd just like to add a few things.

In the old fixed function pipeline, you can set the color of an object using `glColor3f`, so when OpenGL is asked to draw an object (using `glVertex3f`), it will use that color, which kinda answers your questions how can it understand which color to use.

Obviously when making your own shader, you can configure it to work in a similar way, but that's up to you.